# appcenter-cli gives "400 error code" while uploading ipa file to appcenter using appcenter cli

Tags: ios, command-line, build, distribute, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I am working on a script that uploads and distributes the IPA file to a particular group through the app center. To serve this purpose, I am using the app center CLI command **app center distribute release**. 
`appcenter distribute release --token “XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX” --app "ownerName/appName" --group "groupName" --file "path-to-ipa-file" --release-notes "Distributing from local machine" --debug` 
While executing this command, I am getting below error

> / Aborting release upload...Response status code: 200
>   Body: {}
>   Release upload was aborted
>   Error: release binary file uploading failed: HTTP 400 Bad Request

However, I receive this error while uploading the IPA file which is generated through `xcodebuild` command. Just to clarify, the IPA file generated through `xcodebuild` command is working fine in iOS devices. But if I upload the IPA file, which is generated through the app center itself then the same command is working fine and the IPA file is uploaded and distributed successfully on the app center. (Right now I have integrated app center to build the application and distribute it but I am moving the build part somewhere else so I just want to use it as a distribution tool)

I am stuck in this issue from last two weeks. It would be really great if someone can help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

So finally I found the reason behind the issue. I found that the provisioning profile used to build the app was expired and due to that the generated ipa file does contain profile but expired one. So appcenter consider the ipa file is invalid and could not upload it.

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading the ipa manually on `appcenter.ms`. We had this issue when appcenter could not process the binary itself. You will be able too see the error there.

Comment: Good idea to upload it to appcenter, but where can I inspect the error then? I just find this in the upload field: A problem occured while extracting your app. (Correlation ID: 735321b4-fa76-43b4-a403-76bd687c0b6b)